# Context::getContext() how to use in Prestashop Bankwire module

Tags: php, oop, module, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I have some problem with getting delivery country on bankwire order step.
I try in `modules/bankwire/bankwire.php` `function __construct()` with `Context::getContext();` get country name like this:

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$this->context->smarty->assign('country_name', $context->country->name[1]);
```

and nothing. But in Cart.php it works fine with:

```
$context = Context::getContext();
if ($context->country->name[1] == 'Germany') {}
```

Also I try to get country name in same `modules/bankwire/bankwire.php`  like this:

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$delivery = new Address($context->cart->id_address_delivery);
$this->context->smarty->assign('country_name', $delivery->country);
```

And get nothing too. But in `ParentOrderController.php` it works with:

```
$address = new Address($this->context->cart->id_address_delivery);
$this->context->smarty->assign('country_name', $address->country);
```

Please can you tell me how can I get country name in bankwire and how can I use Context::getContext()?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found where is my mistake. I should edit this file `modules/bankwire/controllers/front/payment.php` After this code:

```
public function initContent()
 {
    parent::initContent();

    $cart = $this->context->cart;
    if (!$this->module->checkCurrency($cart))
        Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order');

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'nbProducts' => $cart->nbProducts(),
        'cust_currency' => $cart->id_currency,
        'currencies' => $this->module->getCurrency((int)$cart->id_currency),
        'total' => $cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH),
        'this_path' => $this->module->getPathUri(),
        'this_path_bw' => $this->module->getPathUri(),
        'this_path_ssl' => Tools::getShopDomainSsl(true, true).__PS_BASE_URI__.'modules/'.$this->module->name.'/'
    ));
```

I changed `$this->context->smarty->assign('total'…` to what I need.

But question **Why Context::getContext() doesn't work in bankwire.php?** is still open. If anyone have an idea why `Context::getContext()` doesn't work I would like to hear it.

Thanks.